# What is a way to reload lua scripts during run-time?

Tags: scripting, lua

I want to reload lua scripts at run-time.  What are the ways to do this?  Do you just have to reinitialize the lua system and then re-read all the lua files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If (a) the Lua scripts are in [modules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-module), and (b) the modules don't affect globals or tables outside the scope of the module, you can use `package.loaded.????? = nil` to cause `require` to reload the module:

```
> require "lsqlite3"
> =sqlite3.version
function: 0x10010df50
> sqlite3.version = "33"
> return sqlite3.version
33
> require "lsqlite3"
> return sqlite3.version
33
> package.loaded.lsqlite3 = nil
> return sqlite3.version
33
> require "lsqlite3"
> return sqlite3.version
function: 0x10010c2a0
>
```

Similarly, if the [non-module](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiquedat) scripts are well behaved in that they (a) only define a single table, and (b) don't affect globals or other tables, then simply reloading the script will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use your own `include(filename)` function:

```
function evalfile(filename, env)
    local f = assert(loadfile(filename))
    return f()
end

function eval(text)
    local f = assert(load(text))
    return f()
end

function errorhandler(err)
    return debug.traceback(err)
end

function include(filename)
    local success, result = xpcall(evalfile, errorhandler, filename)

    --print(string.format("success=%s filename=%s\n", success, filename))
    if not success then
        print("[ERROR]\n",result,"[/ERROR]\n")
    end
end

function include_noerror(filename)
    local success, result = xpcall(evalfile, errorhandler, filename)
    --print(string.format("success=%s filename=%s\n", success, filename))
end
```

Comment: you should take into account `package.path` for search path, or your `include()` function will only work with absolute paths

Comment: Yes, you can edit if you want, I'm not using lua in any engine any longer